# Different Memcached services on the Same memcached server

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I am creating different service on the single memcached server as

```
sc create "Memcached11211" binPath= "C:\memcached\memcached.exe -d runservice -p 11211"
DisplayName= "Memcached11211" start= auto

sc create "Memcached11212" binPath= "C:\memcached\memcached.exe -d runservice -p 11212"`  
DisplayName= "Memcached11212" start= auto
```

Will that cause performance overhead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the performance nearly the same, with some minor different. the bottleneck of memcached is usually NetworkIO, if you deploy multi service on the single server, that's no difference.

but there are some good stuff if you has multi service, for example:if one of the memcached service crash, you just lose half of the cached data, and your db will not carry full load for your lost. and if you plan to build a memcached cluster, this is a good way for your code to get ready.

Comment: When i stop and restart the Memcached11211 service then i loose my data which is available on this instance. I don't want my data to loose when i restart the server as it is the property of memcached.please help

Comment: you have to make sure the data persistence yourself, it told you that in the guild of memcached, beside the data will be drop when memcached hit memory limit.